# How to combine split() with float()

Tags: python, split

My Script is reading data from another file.
I require the data as float, not as string and I am searching for an elegant/pythonic way to combine **float()** with the last line instead of iterating over the entire list to change the data or changing it when I need it:

```
    data = []
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), "r") as f:            
        searchlines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):


            data.append(line.replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').split())
```

So far this will save the data from the file in a list in a list as **string**.

**How to combine the last line with float()?**

Here is an example of the data before reading it:

```
    [[ 563.15   1673.97 3078.41]
     [ 563.15   1066.4  26617.7]
     [ 563.212  778.931 59356.1]
```

Comment: you should try : float_data = [float(element) for element in data]

Comment: why the `enumerate`? `data = [[float(x.strip()) for x in line.replace("[","").replace("]", "").split(" ")] for line in searchlines]` should do

Comment: enumerate: this remains from a previous bit of code. kept it as a habit. thx for both solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map`

**Ex:**

```
data.append(map(float, line.strip('[]').split()))
```

If *python3*

```
data.append(list(map(float, line.strip('[]').split())))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to solve it myself with map, but couldn't figure out that it doesn't work due to python3

Comment: I was only waiting for the time limit to pass to mark it as solved :)

Comment: A list comprehension would more pythonic, and prevent a LISP-like bunch of closing parentheses.
`data.append([float(e) for e in line.strip('[]').split()])`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have numpy installed?

Because in that case you can do:

```
import numpy as np

with open(os.path.join(path, file), "r") as f:            
    data = np.array([line.strip('[]').split() for line in f],dtype=float)
```

it gives you a matrix in float format. Of course, this assumes that each line has the same number of values in it

Comment: I do. I will consider it since it might help against inconsistent data sets